# Self homomorphisms of hyperreals fixing the reals

Tags: model-theory, nonstandard-analysis

What do we know about the circumstances (whether having to do with the axioms of set theory or the model itself) under which a field $F$ of hyperreals (=ultrapower of $\mathbb R$ with respect to a non-principal ultrafilter on an infinite set) has this property: For every $x \in F \backslash \mathbb R$ there is a field homomorphism (=monomorphism) of $F$ to itself that fixes $\mathbb R$ and moves $x$?

(It looks to me that saturation is a sufficient condition, even if we replace "homomorphism" with "isomorphism".)

Comment: Closely related to this question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/296575/2126

Comment: What is a "non-standard model of analysis"? What language are you working in? Do you specifically have ultrapowers in mind, or do you allow more general models? (Usually when people talk about the hyperreals, they mean an ultrapower of the reals.)

Comment: I'm ok with restricting to ultrapowers.

Comment: There are certainly models with the property you're interested in which are *not* ultrapowers.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I edited my poor choice of wording to clarify that I am interested in ultrapowers. The language is the language of fields.